# Alarm Manager does not work as expected when scheduling task

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm currently working with Android Alarm Manager and found a working example. But it does not work properly in my situation. Let me explain. Basically my goal is to execute a method from the MainActivity each 5 mins. For this purpose I use Alarm Manager to schedule that task.

Basically this is the working stuff:

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("SERVICE_TEMPORARY_STOPPED"));
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SERVICE_TEMPORARY_STOPPED"));

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAlarm();
            }
        });
    }


    public void startAlarm() {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 300000;
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarm Set");
    }
}
```

Everything is good. "I'm running" Toast is executed every 300000 ms (5 mins). The `AlarmReceiver` class send a broadcast to my main Activity with the message "SERVICE_TEMPORARY_STOPPED". I already registered that message in my MainActivity via `registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SERVICE_TEMPORARY_STOPPED"));`. But, when I add another method, let's say `stopAlarm()` in the broadcastReceiver, which is going to stop the alarm after 5 mins, the time interval (5 mins) is not applied anymore. In something like 10 secs, it calls the Broadcast Receiver and stop the alarm. And this is the issue. Take a look at the `stop()` method and how I call it on the `broadcastReceiver`:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        stopAlarm();
    }
};

public void stopAlarm() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Alarm Cancelled");
}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

**AlarmManager.setRepeating** doesn't work properly on different android versions.

Try **setExact**. It won't repeat but you can achieve repeating functionality as mentioned below:

**Updated AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("SERVICE_TEMPORARY_STOPPED"));

        long repeatCount = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getLong("REPEAT_COUNT", 0L);

        repeatCount++;

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (context).edit().putLong("REPEAT_COUNT", repeatCount).apply()

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (repeatCount *System.currentTimeMillis()),pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Here we maintain a repeatCount & variable (preference based) and increment it in your AlarmReceiver & schedule alarm again by calculating nextAlarmTime using repeatCount * System.currentTimeMillis();